# Adding a validation handler to the registration form

Tags: forms

I have altered the registration form to change the *thank you* message and add the validation of some fields.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][]  = 'checkout_nationality_form_validate';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'thank_on_submit';
  }
```

All code is working fine; my problem is the registration doesn't take the default Drupal validation. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5):

You need to change this line

```
 $form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][]  = 'checkout_nationality_form_validate';
```

to

```
 $form['#validate'][] = 'checkout_nationality_form_validate';
```

Answer (score 4):

Your custom validation function should go into the $form['#validate'] array

```
$form['#validate'] = 'checkout_nationality_form_validate';
```

I prefer using the implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) instead of using an if statement in the hook_form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_form_id_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'checkout_nationality_form_validate';
}

/**
 * Custom validation function.
 */
function checkout_nationality_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if($form_state['value']['my_field'] == 'is not valid') {
    form_set_error('my_field', t('Value not valid'));
  }
}
```